# For all rows select first entry that satisfies a criterion

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have a diary table. Each entry in the diary has a `user_id` and an `entry_date`.
For a range of `user_id`'s I want to select the first entry later than a specified date.

**So with**

```
user_id | entry_date
--------------------
  1     | 2016-11-09 20:00:00
  2     | 2016-11-09 20:00:00
  1     | 2016-11-09 21:00:00
  1     | 2016-11-09 22:00:00
  5     | 2016-11-10 20:00:00
```

**I imagine I can write something like**

```
SELECT user_id,entry_date FROM entries
WHERE entries.user_id BETWEEN 10 AND 20
AND TAKE_FIRST(entries.entry_date >= to_timestamp('2016-11-09 20:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

(Where `TAKE_FIRST()` is a placeholder for what I don't know.)

**such that the result will be**

```
user_id | entry_date
--------------------
  1     | 2016-11-09 21:00:00
  5     | 2016-11-10 20:00:00
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user_id,MIN(entry_date) FROM entries
WHERE entries.user_id BETWEEN 10 AND 20
AND entry_date >= to_timestamp('2016-11-09 20:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
GROUP BY user_id
```

For each user_id in range finds the minimum date greater than that of your choice. It won't work if you need additional data out of `entries` table, but otherwise should be the simplest solution.

Comment: Good eye seeing it can be solved without window functions, +1 . That being said, if he wants more columns, then it won't do:)

Comment: @sagi - it will do fine if he wants more columns, that's what `keep (dense_rank first/last order by entry_date)` is for!

Comment: Yes, if he will use the window function , does it look to you like the OP knows how to do it?.. I just stated that if more columns from the first entry are required, then the code as it is won't work. @mathguy

Comment: @sagi - Why window function? He can use `first/last` AGGREGATE function, no need for analytic functions for this type of requirement. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

Comment: "are aggregate and analytic functions" , Are you sure that this doesn't count as an analytic function? I thought it is, but nevertheless , the OP probably don't know how to use it. @mathguy

Comment: You can use them either as aggregate or as analytic ("window") functions. Here you only need the aggregate version. "The OP probably doesn't know" - that's why they come to SO! :-)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, if the op needs more columns, then this answer as it is won't work, nd he won't know how to adjust it.. @mathguy

Answer (score 1):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT user_id,entry_date 
FROM (
    SELECT user_id,entry_date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY entry_date) as rnk
    FROM entries
    WHERE entries.user_id BETWEEN 10 AND 20
      AND entries.entry_date >= to_timestamp('2016-11-09 20:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
     )
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: I guess there is a problem with performance with all timestamps larger than the specified date will be selected and the from that only 1 is selected. Can the performance be improved?